# how to  set a default 'selected value' on a :collection dropdown/select textfield?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, collections, simple-form

Im trying to make a certain value the default selected one, in a drop down/select textfield. Ive have tried numerous options to no avail. Who knows how to set the default one based on a value from the Profile model?

```
= f.input_field :state_id,
                :label => "Your state",
                :collection => DataState.all,
                :default =>  [DataState.where(:id => @user.profile.state_id)],
                :style => "width: 110px !important"
```

Im using simple_form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `:selected` option?

Try to change the:

```
:default =>  [DataState.where(:id => @user.profile.state_id)],
```

for

```
:selected =>  [DataState.where(:id => @user.profile.state_id)],
```

Comment: Tried didn't work.. very frustrating these form issues just setting a value as default that it can be so hard :(

Answer (score 1):

I think, You have to give ID# instead of whole object

Try this,

```
:default =>  [DataState.where(:id => @user.profile.state_id).id],
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah use this. It works:

```
:selected =>  [DataState.where(:id => @user.profile.state_id).first.id],
```